# How to solve this integral with $|x|$ from $-\infty $ to $\infty$

Tags: calculus, integration

So I thought I solve this integral, but I think I'm missing a step because I'm ending up with a value of 0, when the solution says it should be something else. This is what i'm trying to take the integral of.

$$h(x) =-\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda |x|}\cdot ln(\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda |x|})dx  $$
$$ =-\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda |x|}\cdot[ ln(\frac{\lambda}{2}) -\lambda |x|]dx  $$
$$ =-\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda |x|}\cdot ln(\frac{\lambda}{2})dx + \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\lambda^2}{2} |x|e^{-\lambda |x|}dx  $$
$$ = \frac{1}{2}e^{-\lambda|x|}ln(\frac{\lambda}{2}) - \frac{\lambda}{2}|x|e^{-\lambda |x|} - \frac{1}{2}e^{-\lambda |x|}  \space \space \space \space \space \space \space  from -\infty \space to \space  \infty $$

this is what i end up with, and I think since it's an absolute value of $x$, I should split it and go from $-\infty$ to $0$ and $0$ to $\infty$ and then add them together, but if i do that, won't I get something like:

$$ [\frac{1}{2}ln(\frac{\lambda}{2}) - \frac{1}{2} ] - [\frac{1}{2}ln(\frac{\lambda}{2}) - \frac{1}{2} ] = 0\space ?$$

I'm sure I'm just missing something silly, but I'm not sure what it is. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Your integrand is even, not odd, so splitting the integral at $0$ and summing amounts to integrating from $0$ to $\infty$ and multiplying by $2$.

Comment: ahh, of course! that was my intuition, but it didn't seem correct. Thinking about it as an even function makes a lot of sense. Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so this has an answer: The integrand is even, and absolutely convergent as an improper integral. Consequently, you can integrate from $0$ to $\infty$ and multiply by $2$. Replacing $|x|$ by $x$ and making the substitution $u = \lambda x$ gives
\begin{align*}
h(x) &= -\int_{-\infty}^\infty \tfrac{\lambda}{2} e^{-\lambda |x|} \cdot \ln(\tfrac{\lambda}{2} e^{-\lambda |x|})\, dx \\
  &= -2\int_{0}^\infty \tfrac{\lambda}{2} e^{-\lambda x} \cdot \ln(\tfrac{\lambda}{2} e^{-\lambda x})\, dx \\
  &= -\int_{0}^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda x} \cdot (\ln\tfrac{\lambda}{2} - \lambda x)\, dx \\
  &= \int_{0}^\infty e^{-u} \cdot (u - \ln\tfrac{\lambda}{2})\, du \\
  &= 1 - \ln\tfrac{\lambda}{2}.
\end{align*}